# Detecting when last file has finished uploading?

Tags: javascript, jquery, fine-uploader

I am using [fine uploader](https://github.com/Widen/fine-uploader) to handle the uploading of files in a web application I have.  Is there some sort of callback for when the last file has finished processing?  I found the `onComplete` callback, but this is fired when every file completes.  I need to know when *all* files are done.  Does anyone know of a way to do this with fine uploader?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ended up going this route:

```
        var uploader = $("#upload").fineUploader({
            request: {
                endpoint: postUrl
            },
            template: uploadTemplate
        }).on('submit',function(){
            fileCount++;
        }).on('complete', function (event, id, name, responseJSON) {

            fileCount--;
            if(fileCount == 0){
                     alert("done!");
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't think fine uploader provides what you're asking for, but it's easy to do this yourself.  You can increment a count in the onSubmit callback, and decrement it in the onComplete callback.  When the count reaches 0 in onComplete, that means all the files have processed.